# UK Standard Visit Visa - Apply separately for spouse?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I have recently applied for UK standard visit visa and in my application, I have been asked questions about my spouse (such as her passport number, date of birth, etc) and whether she will be travelling with me or not (she will). However, the document checklist is only for myself and the address of appointment is given only for my name.

My question is: Is it only my biometrics or does my spouse has to come along as well?

Comment: If your spouse is traveling with you, then you need to fill a separate application and biometrics will also be collected; and both applications (yours and your spouse's) will be linked together in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it only my biometrics or does my spouse has to come along as well?

Your application  looks like it is only for you. You do need to provide details of your spouse as you already have, but she does not need to appear for bio-metrics on your appointment.

However if she is also travelling with you she needs to go through the same process, starting from her own visa application and her own VFS appointment.

Comment: So if I have mentioned in "my" application that "my spouse will be travelling with me", My spouse also needs to start a new application and pay fee and attend biometrics appointment. Is that true?

Comment: Exactly, Yes. Then you can take 2 appointments at the VAC close to each other and go together and they will handle the rest

Comment: In terms of "documents to support the application", I should be submitting all the bank statements and pay slips and address proof and she doesn't need to submit anything except approval to travel abroad. That's because she is a dependent and doesn't work. Is that right?